# How to use select to convert Unit Of Measurement from 1 level to other using T-Sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table keep items Unit of Measurement and it's qty look like this

```
| ItemID |  Qty  |  UOM  |  Factor  | Level |
+--------+-------+-------+----------+-------+
|   9    |   0   |   ctn |    48    |   1   |
|   9    |   1   |   Can |    380   |   2   |
|   9    |   0   |   ML  |    1     |   3   |
```

It means item number 9 UOMs are

1ctn = 48can

1can = 380ML

and this item still has 1can(qty)

I would like to convent 1can to ctn or ML by using T-Sql select script.

Please help me ! Thanks!

Comment: Please state the expected output with more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an unknown number of levels you could use a recursive common table expression to loop through all the possible levels:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  t1.ItemID, 
            UnitFrom = t1.UOM, 
            UnitTo = t2.UOM, 
            Factor = CAST(t2.Factor AS DECIMAL(15, 2)), 
            NextLevelFactor = t1.Factor,
            t1.Level
    FROM    T t1
            INNER JOIN T t2
                ON t2.ItemID = t1.ItemID
                AND t2.Level + 1 = t1.Level
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t1.ItemID, 
            UnitFrom = t2.UOM, 
            UnitTo = t1.UnitTo, 
            Factor = CAST(t1.Factor * t1.NextLevelFactor AS DECIMAL(15, 2)),
            NextLevelFactor = t2.Factor,
            t2.Level
    FROM    CTE t1
            INNER JOIN T t2
                ON t2.ItemID = t1.ItemID
                AND t2.Level = t1.Level + 1
)
SELECT  ItemID,
        UnitFrom,
        UnitTo,
        Factor
FROM    CTE;
```

The result of this is a conversion table:

```
ItemID  UnitFrom    UnitTo  Factor
9       Can         ctn     48
9       ML          Can     380
9       ML          ctn     18240
```

that you can then join to your main table to get the conversion factor between all levels.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11a0e/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    t1.itemid, t1.uom, t1.level,
    isnull(nullif(1.0*t2.qty,0)/t1.factor,0) as  qty_calc
from table t1
join table t2
    on  t1.itemid=t2.itemid
    and t1.Level+1=t2.Level
```

That's for calculating upper levels (ctn) in this case. For lower levels (ml), you'd change join to `t1.Level=t2.Level+1`, and calculation operator to multiplication instead of division.